# How do I simply set up an alert/reminder for dates set in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, alerts, reminders

I have a database in MS Access and within it I am holding dates for expirations for SSL's. I want to set a reminder for any SSL that is soon to expire. Anyone know the easiest way to go about this?

Comment: Access isn't Outlook. :S

Comment: I know, but isn't there a way to set reminders for dates in Access?

Comment: It is not too difficult to automate Outlook from Access.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how you want the notification to work.

- You can pop-up a form when the database opens

  - or at any time using a timer
  - or in a form event
- You can build events into Outlook
- You can run some script in the task manager
- You can send an email using any of the above.

The easiest way to pop-up a form may be to create a form that runs when the database opens or when the menu form opens. This can be set in the start-up options. The form should be based on a query that checks for out of date records and is only made visible if there is data. You can check the recordset in the load event to see if anything is returned. This for can also use DoCmd.SendObject to send an email.

Comment: I would like the notification to be sent in an email if that is possible.

Comment: If you know how to set a pop-up form reminder when the database opens that would be great too.